# Changing Button Title from Storyboard don't reflect changes

Tags: ios, localization, xcode-storyboard

I am facing a weird problem i.e:
My Button title is not what i mentioned in storyboard after build.The Button is getting title from other button near to it. 
What i tried already is:

1. I have verified that Object ID of both button are different.
2. I clean the project and built again.
3. I Uninstalled the app and from simulator and tried again.
4. I restarted the Xcode and checked again.
5. And Also from code i am not changing title of any button infect no ref# or outlet in code.

> If i remove the title from storyboard and Run it reflect the change and show empty title there! that is Normal behaviour, But when i put any other title it show nearest element title not own.

Also if i set title from Controller `[self.basicInfo setTitle:@"Basic Info" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`it change the text and solves the issue.

But My Point is why it is behaving like this and where is the problem.

I have Attached the image file where you can see that in storyboard it show text "Basic information" but after running it shows HOW TO BUY.

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly put a minimal reproducible project up somewhere (like Github)?

Comment: Check if you aren't changing the title in some part of your code

Comment: I am not changing title of any button from code

Comment: @Malik Actually i am not facing this issue every time its with one button only i don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: The reason I asked for a minimal project is because it could be anything ranging from "title being set in some part of the code" as pointed out by Reinier Melian to "Additional button being present in storyboard". In order to rule out human error, I would have to look at the setup and I'm sure you wouldn't want your whole codebase available publicly. Hence the request for a minimal project

Comment: Also, just as a sanity check, try deleting `Derived Data` and `Clean` project

Comment: @Malik i have deleted the Derived Data and checked again but still the same. i can put view Hierarchy of xib where you can see there is no additional View that can cause problem

Comment: @IntsabHaider check if your storyboard is being translated , check if you have defined a translation for that label text

Comment: Yes i did translation

Comment: @IntsabHaider that is the problem then

Comment: so what should i do??

Comment: change the text associated to that label in your storyboard.string

Comment: @IntsabHaider try deleting button and add new button in storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that you have your storyboard localized, so you need to search in your (**StoryBoardName.string**) the Label object id ie: `"YR7-n7-RFZ.text" = "testText";` and change the value after equal sign

[image]

here you have an tutorial about this topic
https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881

Comment: Actually i copied the button and paste it but as its reference in Arabic and English Strings Localization  was same so thats why it was giving the problem! I changes the object ref# there and now it fine. 
Thanks for getting tricky point.